# Java 8 - Loading signed applet always displays a message box

Tags: java, applet, signed-applet, thawte

I've just signed my applet with a certificate from Thawte and now when I load it from my web page I get a information popup that says "Do you want to run this application?" It's a "good" message box according to the java help because it identifies who signed the code and trusts it however I see no way of getting rid it of it cause it's annoying.

I tried to add my site to the exception list but no luck, on the previous java versions there used to be a checkbox that said "Always trust content from this publisher", well, I can't seem to get that checkbox to show up on Java 8, I suppose it doesn't exist anymore.

I would really appreciate any help here.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [link](http://java.com/faq-securityprompts), a security prompt will ask for confirmation before allowing Java content  to run in the browser. You can't prevent it showing it on the first time.

Quoting the information available on the link above:

> The messages presented depends upon different risk factors, such as
>   using old versions of Java or running applet code that is not signed
>   from a trusted Certificate Authority. Apps that present a lower risk
>   display a simple informational message. This includes an option to
>   prevent showing similar messages for apps from the same publisher in
>   the future.

Even running applets from Oracle, such as [JavaFX Samples](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/javafx/2/samples/Ensemble/index.html), you'll see a prompt like this:

[image]

**Update:** According to this [link](http://java.com/en/download/help/trusted_signed_variations.xml), a security prompt doesn't show the option *Do not show this again for apps from the publisher and location above* if  you are hosting the application on multiple locations:

[image]

Comment: Right on the money Cássio! I happened to host my applet on a separate domain so that's why I'm not getting the check box. Thank you so much!